# Drupal7 | Time shows differently in Frontend and Backend

Tags: datetime

The front end time shows as 3 hours behind the backend time of the same page.
The correct time is the one on the backend. 
I set the time-zone correctly for the user and also
the time show correctly in the "Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » date and Time"
[image]

Here is the time that the page shows on the Backend (the correct time):
[image]

And here is the time showing on the front-end (3 hours behind)
[image]

And here is the code that I am using in the page template file:

```
`<?php print "Last Updated: " . format_date($node->changed, $type = 'medium'); ?>`
```

I am developing this Website locally on my machine (localhost).
Any Ideas to get the time correct on the front end?
Thanks.

Comment: You are using the same user when viewing the front/backend?

Comment: Yes I am the only admin for this website. No other users.

Comment: Have you tried to check the current time (not the node's timestamp)? Is the current time also different? Just to be clear - I mean the PHP `time()` function

Comment: Yes when I use the PHP time() function in the code, it outputs the correct local time. Thanks for any other feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

Just in case someone else got the same problem over this.
Here is what I was doing wrong (Thanks to Jay from Princeton University for pointing it out):

I set up the Date & Time for the administrator account under "/admin/people", but not the system-wide setting, which is at "/admin/config/regional/settings"

'Administration -> Regional & Language -> Date And Time' will show the date/time formats I have set up while respecting the user-chosen timezone (not the system-wide default time zone) so everything looks deceptively like it's how I want it until I log out.

So in short there is another time setting in .../admin/config/regional/settings
that I wasn't aware off.